# Validation not working (Directive scope.$error is not populated although ng-invalid class is applied to DOM element)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Updated: also, if anyone can tell me how to simplify my code, I would really appreciate that.

**In short:**
I have simple validation rule applied to element

```
<div ng-form='myForm'>
 <input ng-model='row.item[0].field' required />
</div>
```

I also have style to color invalid entry

```
 .ng-invalid { background:red }
```

And when I remove value from input box it's background color is changed, however neither `row` nor `row.item` , `row.item[0]` and `row.item[0].field` has `$error` property appeared. `myForm.$error` doesn't have anything as well.

So I cannot print validation message bellow input box

**Longer explanation:**

I could have much broader problem than that. Here is my setup (simplified) :

Markup:

Code:

```
function tableCtrl($scope) {

   var fields  = $scope.fields = [
       { name: 'events', required: true }
      ,{ name: 'subjects' }
      ,{ name: 'affected'}]

   $scope.events = [{ name : 'e', type :'some', organ :'blood'
                  , items : [{ events : 1, subjects: 2, affected : 3 }
                             ,{ events : 1, subjects: 2, affected : 3 }
                             ,{ events : 1, subjects: 2, affected : 3 } ] }
                 , { name:'f', type : 'any', organ :'heart'
                    , items :[{ events : 1, subjects: 2, affected : 3 }
                             ,{ events : 1, subjects: 2, affected : 3 }
                             ,{ events : 1, subjects: 2, affected : 3 } ]}
                 , { name: 'g', type: 'all', organ :'skin'
                    , items : [{ events : 1, subjects: 2, affected : 3 }
                             ,{ events : 1, subjects: 2, affected : 3 }
                             ,{ events : 1, subjects: 2, affected : 3 } ]}]

}
angular.module('components').directive('editor', function ($compile) {
return {
    scope : {
        row : '=editor'          
        , fields : '=fields'
    },        
    terminal:true,

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       var tmpl = ''

       for (var g in row.items ) {
           var itemPath = 'row.items['+g+']'
            for (var f in scope.fields) {
                tmpl += '<td><input type="number" ng-model="'+itemPath+'.'+scope.fields[f].name + '"' +
                  ' min="0"  ' +
                    (scope.fields[f].required? ' required ' : '' )+                           
                    ' /></td>'
            }             
       }   

       var newElement = angular.element(tmpl);
       $compile(newElement)(scope);
       element.replaceWith(newElement); 
    }        
}
```

So I'm creating input boxes dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation is related to ng-form and ng-model directive which means you need either a `<form>` element or `<ng-form` element with a name for validation to work.

Then you can access the valid state in the scope using `formname.$error`.

```
<form name="myform">
    <input ng-model='row.item[0].field' required />
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myform.$error" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: I probably need to update my question, I do have `<div ng-form='formCtrl'>` in my markup and formCtrl.$error doesn't have anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile the new element on the parent scope, not on the isolated scope. It worked on my case.

```
$compile(newElement)(scope.$parent);
```